# Foreign Key linking with primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, key

I have few questions regarding foreign key linking with primary key and please explain reason behind it. They are below

1. Can any foreign key, act as primary key for some other foreign key ?
   -> I think it will work but foreign key (which act as primary key) must have 1-1 relationship with its primary key, it must be unique and not null
2. Can one foreign key refer two or more primary key ?
   -> I have read somewhere on stackoverflow that one foeign key refer to one table (one table has one primary key), but didn't found appropriate explaination anywhere.

Comment: I see it the opposite way, a fk points at a pk.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys and primary keys are independent.  Foreign keys "reach out" to other tables.  Primary keys are insular, they describe a particular table.

So, a foreign key always points to another table.  Within the table where it is defined, the foreign key can be:

- A primary key
- Part of a composite primary key
- Nothing to do with the primary key

Two columns in the same table can be foreign keys to the same primary key in another table.

Your second point doesn't really make sense.  Primary keys don't reference foreign keys.  The relationship is the other way around.

Comment: I have updated my question, Can one foreign key refer to two or more primary key ?